# How to create a looping variable to use in a axios call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, foreach, axios

I have a queryUrl that is has dynamic its filters created dynamically. Basically what I need to do is take the users input data and loop through all possible input id's.

Something like this

```
var search = ""
document.getElementByTagName("input").map(function(){
if (search != '')
search =+ '&';
search =+ 'filter=' + document.querySelectorAll('id'); + "|" + document.val();
});
search: function() {
return axios.get("http://api/document?" + search)
}
```

Comment: You can't (and you must not) one-to-one translate a jQuery model to React. They are totally different type of programming.
Start reading about how react works before writing code, it will save you hours.

Comment: Right. It just feels like I'm so close. Currently I'm using all the data in the api and setting the contracts state to that. I was hoping I could instead use the model to only use the searched terms and set the state to that.